# SNS Push Notification with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I have gone through the documentation of [node-push-notification-sns-transport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-push-notification-sns-transport) and I have implemented in my code which is perfectly working fine for the first time but second time it is showing me `platform already configured` then I have to cut the execution and rebuild and rerun then It works fine. Where I am going wrong?

```
sns = (req, res) => {
    push.addTransport(new SnsTransport({
        aws: {
            accessKeyId: cache.get('AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY'),
            secretAccessKey: cache.get('AMAZON_SECRET_KEY'),
            region: cache.get('AMAZON_REGION'),
            apiVersions: {
                sns: '2010-03-31'
            }
        },
        platformAppArn: 'arn:aws:sns:us-xxx-1:XXXXXX:app/GCM/Test'
    }));
    // Send a push notification via SNS.
    push.send('sns', 'device_token', {
        alert: 'how is it going?'
    }, (err, data) => {

        if (err) {
            res.send(err, req);
        } else {
            res.send(data);
        }


    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you using express framework? I see `(req, res) => {` syntax is so familiar.

If it that true, you only need configure push notifications via AWS SNS once time. Just config your transport out of handler function, make sure that it only run once time.

```
push.addTransport(new SnsTransport({
  aws: {
    accessKeyId: cache.get('AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY'),
    secretAccessKey: cache.get('AMAZON_SECRET_KEY'),
    region: cache.get('AMAZON_REGION'),
    apiVersions: {
      sns: '2010-03-31'
    }
  },
  platformAppArn: 'arn:aws:sns:us-xxx-1:XXXXXX:app/GCM/Test'
}));

sns = (req, res) => {
  // Send a push notification via SNS.
  push.send('sns', 'device_token', {
    alert: 'how is it going?'
  }, (err, data) => {

    if (err) {
      res.send(err, req);
    } else {
      res.send(data);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I have hardcoded `platformAppArn`. Is there is anyway to get dynamically from AWS ?

Comment: I have put the transport out of handler and its throwing `Error: cannot send to unsupported platform sns`

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the option in the send method like this:

```
push.send('sns', 'DEVICE_TOKEN', { alert: 'how is it going?' }, { isEndpoint: true } ,(err, data) => {
  console.log(err);
  console.log(data);
});
```

Also, remove the platform App ARN from the addTransport method above.

Comment: I have hardcoded `platformAppArn`. Is there is anyway to get dynamically from AWS ?

Comment: I have removed `platformAppArn` from `addTransport` method and its throwing `Invalid parameter: TargetArn Reason: An ARN must have at least 6 elements, not 2`